# BB Code List Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, bbcode

I am currently implimenting a easy to edit BB code script which is written up with Jquery / Javascript. Only problem is it's not as easy as I would like and so I need some help.

The script works fine (adding stuff into the textarea). However I am trying to make the presentation a little better.

I would appreciate it if someone could tell me how to unlist the items or at least hide the buttet points (probably do this using css) otherwise I could edit the javascript/jquery.

Also when I scroll over an option (for the bold button) it shows the  code to the button (as a title) I would like to remove this but I can't see where on the code I'd edit it.

[image: Screenshot of list/bb options]

**Here is my javascript code:**

```
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// markItUp!
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Copyright (C) 2008 Jay Salvat
// http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
myBbcodeSettings = {
  nameSpace:          "bbcode", // Useful to prevent multi-instances CSS conflict
  previewParserPath:  "~/sets/bbcode/preview.php",
  markupSet: [
      {name:"<img src='_img/bold_icon.gif'>", key:'B', openWith:'[b]', closeWith:'[/b]'}, 
      {name:'Italic', key:'I', openWith:'[i]', closeWith:'[/i]'}, 
      {name:'Underline', key:'U', openWith:'[u]', closeWith:'[/u]'}, 
      {separator:'---------------' },
      {name:'Picture', key:'P', replaceWith:'[img][![Url]!][/img]'}, 
      {name:'Link', key:'L', openWith:'[url=[![Url]!]]', closeWith:'[/url]', placeHolder:'Your text to link here...'},
      {separator:'---------------' },
      {name:'Colors', openWith:'[color=[![Color]!]]', closeWith:'[/color]', dropMenu: [
          {name:'Yellow', openWith:'[color=yellow]', closeWith:'[/color]', className:"col1-1" },
          {name:'Orange', openWith:'[color=orange]', closeWith:'[/color]', className:"col1-2" },
          {name:'Red', openWith:'[color=red]', closeWith:'[/color]', className:"col1-3" },
          {name:'Blue', openWith:'[color=blue]', closeWith:'[/color]', className:"col2-1" },
          {name:'Purple', openWith:'[color=purple]', closeWith:'[/color]', className:"col2-2" },
          {name:'Green', openWith:'[color=green]', closeWith:'[/color]', className:"col2-3" },
          {name:'White', openWith:'[color=white]', closeWith:'[/color]', className:"col3-1" },
          {name:'Gray', openWith:'[color=gray]', closeWith:'[/color]', className:"col3-2" },
          {name:'Black', openWith:'[color=black]', closeWith:'[/color]', className:"col3-3" }
      ]},
      {name:'Size', key:'S', openWith:'[size=[![Text size]!]]', closeWith:'[/size]', dropMenu :[
          {name:'Big', openWith:'[size=200]', closeWith:'[/size]' },
          {name:'Normal', openWith:'[size=100]', closeWith:'[/size]' },
          {name:'Small', openWith:'[size=50]', closeWith:'[/size]' }
      ]},
      {separator:'---------------' },
      {name:'Bulleted list', openWith:'[list]\n', closeWith:'\n[/list]'}, 
      {name:'Numeric list', openWith:'[list=[![Starting number]!]]\n', closeWith:'\n[/list]'}, 
      {name:'List item', openWith:'[*] '}, 
      {separator:'---------------' },
      {name:'Quotes', openWith:'[quote]', closeWith:'[/quote]'}, 
      {name:'Code', openWith:'[code]', closeWith:'[/code]'}, 
      {separator:'---------------' },
      {name:'Clean', className:"clean", replaceWith:function(h) { return h.selection.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/g, "") } },
      {name:'Preview', className:"preview", call:'preview' }
   ]
}
```

Thank you for any help you can give me! :)

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP to parse and a simple script to add in text.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try to use a composer packagist BB code. See: https://packagist.org/?q=bbcode&idx=packagist&p=0